# How to build my own embeddable audio player // not pure flash

Tags: html, audio, mp3, html5-audio, embeddable

We are currently developing a community based on user-generated audio content. The base technology for playing audio <s>will be Soundmanager 2</s> is HTML5. We created our own player interface based on <s>the SM2 options</s> jQuery.

In order to make the uploaded mp3 files embeddable I am currently looking for the right technology. The player must be playable on mobile devices (which excludes pure flash players, I assume). Traffic leaks should be avoidable.

**What is the best approach to create an embeddable player snippet regarding cross-browser (and cross-device) compatibility and security?**

IMHO, those are the options:

- Embed with an `<iframe>` tag (like Facebook offers)
- Embed with a `<script>` tag (that "injects" the player code into the DOM).
- Just offer a shortened HTML markup snippet, with all links made absolute (CSS, JS,
  images)

**EDIT**: To avoid misreading: I am talking about an embedding code that can be offered to our visitors, so they can use *our* player on *their* remote websites. Yes, like Youtube or Soundcloud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used SM2, so I can't speak to that.

However, if jQuery is an option, I've had good luck with [jquery.mb.miniAudioPlayer](http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/jquery-mb-miniaudioplayer/), which is based on [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org).

Here's an example of the minimal amount of markup/code required:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery/1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/mbScrollable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $(".audio").mb_miniAudioPlayer({
        width:240,
        inLine:false
      });
    });
</script>

<div id="myScroll">
    <a id="m1" 
        class="audio {ogg:'http://www.miaowmusic.com/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg',
        mp3:'http://www.miaowmusic.com/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3'}"
        href="javascript:void(0)">miaowmusic - Bubble (mp3/ogg)
    </a>
</div>
```

(as seen on [this page](http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb.miniAudioPlayer/miniAudioPlayer.html)—click 'how to'.)

Or in other words, to use your breakdown: yes, there's a `<script>` tag that "injects" the player code into the DOM.

Comment: jQuery is always an option! (if not the answer)

Comment: @Trufa - Yeah, I figure I can never go wrong recommending jQuery on SO…

Comment: No you can't :) BTW this is good stuff!

Comment: Yes, jQuery is an option. In your example, the < script > tag has to be placed in the document header. If I wrap the whole bunch into one < div > for the document body, will it still work? Remember it has to work on remote websites (blogs etc.), not only on ours.

Comment: @Mateng - I haven't tried that, so I can't say for sure—but I suspect it would work just fine.

Comment: @Dori, you are right. I used another player to test that, changed the paths to absolute (incl. domains) and it worked. As simple as that.

Comment: @Mateng - Glad to hear it, and thanks for the update!